# Tuckey rewrite filter pretty URL gets lost when non-ajax JSF form is submitted

Tags: jsf, url-rewriting, form-submit, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

On my login form (login.xhtml which is rewritten to /login)

```
public void test(){

}

<h:commandButton  id="loginButton" value="Login"
                        action="#{loginBean.test}" 
                    />
```

The problem is when the button is clicked the form redirects from /login -> /login.xhtml. How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use PrimeFaces command button instead? The standard command button doesn't do ajax by default and doesn't support `update` attribute at all. This is just a typo question. Take a break and get some caffein ;)

Comment: @BalusC I was using primefaces with ajax=false but tried to generalize the question (I've removed the update attribute now). If I use primefaces when ajax = true it works fine as the page doesn't refresh. However if I use primefaces with ajax=false or the standard command button when I submit the page refreshes and the URL redirects to the .xhtml version.

Comment: @BalusC Any suggested workaround for this?

Comment: Custom view handler.